# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps freezing and does not take any inputs

Tags: 14.04

GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] Nvidia Graphics card, and have ubuntu 14.04 os. Every 10 minutes or so it freezes. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is my temporary solution. What do I do to fix this?

lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2 gives the following output:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1447

Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1447
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: I think you missed a number after the second Alt+Ctrl+F

Comment: have you tried to install the proprietary video driver for it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, re-installing the latest driver would the first step of course. First try using the *Software & Updates* to install the latest ***proprietary*** and preferably ***tested*** driver.

Open the **Ubuntu Software Center**, move your mouse to the top, from the **Edit** menu, choose **Software Sources** . Click on **Additional Drivers** tab, wait for it to load the information and choose the latest proprietary for the NVIDIA. For me (GeForce GT 730) at this time it shows:

```
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.59 from nvidia-346 (proprietary, tested)
```

Click on **Apply** and wait for it to install it. If your screen keeps crashing during this process, then you won't have a choice other than trying to install it from terminal.

Comment: I did all that you said - version 331.113 from nvidia331 was the only proprietary, tested that was available. The problem still persists.

Comment: Is your machine a dual boot by any chance? Or, can you try your graphic card on a different machine to see if you get a similar problem or not? There are several scenarios in my mind at the moment such as: 1- hardware malfunction (graphic card) 2- Your graphic card drivers are not fully Compatibile with Ubuntu, although one would not expect it from NVidia but it has happened to me. 3- Communication problem between motherboard and graphic card coming from different things such as motherboard driver, etc.

Answer (score -1):

just fire up a terminal , and run the following. I hope it will work.
step 1.setup xorgs edgers ppa.

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa and then sudo apt-get
>   update sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

step 2.now run the following

> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-349

you can substitute 349 with whatever new version it has now.

step 3.add current user to bumblebee security group.

> sudo adduser bumblebee $USER

just do this and reboot after installation, recheck whether the problem exists or not.